# PHP: session not saved

Tags: php, session

My session variables in PHP aren't saved.

In my login form the user logins and the page redirects to exec.php:

```
...
$_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
echo $_SESSION["username"] ==> works fine
//header("Location: home.php");
...
```

When I use the header instruction to return to the homepage after the session is set, the session variable is lost en I get following msg:

Undefined index: username in D:\www.xxx on line x

My session_start() statement is the very first statement on my php page. Maybe there's a problem with the timeout settings of sessions?

Thx for your help...

Comment: Do you have session_start() on the top of both pages?

Comment: No only on the login.php page. Is it necessary to do it on both pages??

Comment: Yes, it is nice when you post only the code you think is important and make us easier to understand, but in this case, I am pretty sure you should have posted everything right from the start up to and including  the first access of variables in $_SESSION in both files.

Comment: Yes it is necessary on both pages.

Comment: That could be the reason why it doesn't work. I'll include the session_start() instruction on both pages and check it again when I'm back from work. Thx a lot!

Comment: So now is your code working Mr.Willems

Comment: BTW stop mentioning line when "I'm back from work" or "when I'm back to home"

Comment: OOPS didnt checked the comments :D

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

Now first go and run `phpinfo()` then search for `session` and check `Registered save handlers` if no `memcache` is written check for `session.save_path` if not set properly, set it by editing your `php.ini` file.

if dont have access to the `php.ini` file. just insert your code in php file for setting the save path of sessions.

**NOTE:** Must set the directory with write permissions. i.e. `CHMOD 777`

Answer (score 0):

your `session_start()` statement is in header?? if not then this could be the problem

Comment: Yes it is in header.php at line 1. Probably my error is due to the fact that I havn't written the session_start() stmnt in the exec.php file @Andrius Naruševičius

Comment: have you included your header.php in your exec.php?